# Enviar dados de EditText para um ListView em outra activity

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber uma forma de enviar um dado digitado pelo usuário em um edittext e enviar para outra activity e atualizar uma listView com dados ja inseridos. Tenho um classe chamada Editar prancha e outra MainActivity que extende FragmentActivity. Na classe main tenho um arrayList que possue alguns dados ja inseridos nele, porem quando tento enviar os dados do editText para a main e inserir neste array não funciona.Exite alguma forma de fazer isso?
Classe Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
private EditarPrancha editarPrancha;
private ListView listItemView;
private ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    inserirArray("INICIO");
    inserirArray("PERGUNTAS");
    inserirArray("RESPOSTAS");

    exibeListaDeCategorias();
    transitarEntreFragmentos();
}
public void inserirArray (String valor){
    lista.add(valor);
}

public ArrayList<String> retornaLista() {

    return lista;
}


//exibe lista com categorias
public void exibeListaDeCategorias(){
    listItemView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, retornaLista());
    listItemView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listItemView.invalidate();
}
```

Class Editar:

```
public class EditarPrancha extends FragmentActivity{

private MainActivity mainActivity;
private ListView listItemView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_editar_prancha);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    adicionarNovaCategoria();
    selecionaCategoriaParaAlterar();
    botaoSelecionarImagem();
}

public void adicionarNovaCategoria(){
    Button btAdicionar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.salvar);
    btAdicionar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText txtCat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadastrar_categoria);
            //capta o valor do txtCat

            String cat = txtCat.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(EditarPrancha.this, "" +cat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (cat.length() > 0) {
                txtCat.setText("");
                txtCat.findFocus();
                mainActivity.inserirArray(cat);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(EditarPrancha.this, "Digite o nome da categoria", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não consegue instanciar uma activity como está fazendo e simplesmente atribuir valores como fez em: `mainActivity.inserirArray(cat);`, o Android não funciona assim por questões de segurança. Para isso, você precisa usar um intent.

Na classe Editar, faça o seguinte:

```
if (cat.length() > 0) {

  //Cria um intent com os parâmetros indicando de onde ele vem e para onde ele vai.
  Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainAcivity.class);

  //insere a string no intent com um nome qualquer.
  intent.putExtra("nomeQualquer",cat);

  //carrega a outra tela levando o intent junto.
  startActivity(intent);

  //todos os 3 resumidos a uma linha
  startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class).putExtra("nomeQualquer",cat));
}
```

Na Main, dentro do onCreate:

```
String cat;
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent.hasExtra("nomeQualquer")){
  cat = intent.getStringExtra("nomeQualquer");
}
```

Quando você fizer o hasExtra e o getStringExtra no "nomeQualquer", apesar de poder ser qualquer nome, precisa ser o mesmo que você criou no putExtra.

O putExtra aceita todos os tipos de variáveis mas não objetos inteiros. Para isso você precisa usar um Bundle, guardar o objeto dentro dele e depois guardar o Bundle no putExtra.

Comment: O meu está dando erro no                 startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class).putExtra("nomeQualquer",cat));  /entre o this e o MainActivity.class não sei porque

Comment: Pode ser o "extends" da classe. Se for a main, tente extender Activity ou AppCompatActivity. 

Os parâmetros do Intent são "de onde vem" e "para onde vai", sendo que a primeira parte precisa ser a classe onde você está no momento. O "de onde vem" é o contexto atual, ou seja, você pode passar o this indicando que é a própria classe, ou talvez MainActivity.this.

Tente fazer separado e poste o erro, se eu puder ajudar eu o farei.

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity.class).putExtra("nomeQualquer",cat)); Isso resolve o problema.